# how many ratings a tradesman had when the employer accepted his quote: 2 cases, male and female employers

Tags: mysql

I have an app where employers can post a job description, tradesmen submit a quote, and the employer can select one of those quotes. After the job is done, both parties can rate each other.

Now I want to find out how many ratings a tradesman had when the employer accepted his quote, and I want to know that for 2 cases: 1) male employers and 2) female employers

Below a simpel db-schema (mysql), I listed only the important db-fields:

- users: id, title (mr or mrs; -> male or female employer), role_id (1: employer, 2: tradesman)
- jobs: id, users_id
- quotes: id, job_id, user_id (tradesman who quoted on the job), accepted_at (timestamp)
- ratings: id, job_id, rater_id (user who rated), assessee_id (user who get rated), created_at (timestamp)

So far I know how to list all successful jobs and the corresponding employers and tradesmen:

```
select
  u.id as user_id,
  u.title,
  j.id as job_id,
  j.title,
  q.id as quote_id,
  q.user_id as tradesman_id,
  q.accepted_at
from users u
  inner join jobs j on j.user_id = u.id
  inner join quotes q on q.job_id = j.id
where q.accepted_at is not null
```

And I know how to make a simple query to list all ratings of a tradesman has received:

```
select
  u.id as user_id,
  u.username as assessee_username,
  r.id as r_id,
  r.created_at
from users u inner join ratings r on assessee_id = u.id
where r.rating_type = 1
group by r.id
```

But I somehow need to connect the dots, I want to know how many ratings a tradesman had when the employer selected his quote, and this for 2 cases: 1) male employers and 2) female employers. I just don't get it how to structure my queries...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What happens if a user hires the same tradesman multiple times?
What if a tradesman hires another tradesman?  It seems like a person can only be a tradesman OR an employer but not both.

Why not just make this a simple query since you should already know what the job & quote are and who the tradesman is?

Known info: tradesman_user_id, quotes_accepted_at

```
SELECT u.title, COUNT(*)
FROM ratings AS r
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON r.rater_id = u.id
WHERE r.created_at < [quotes_accepted_at]
    AND assessee_id = [tradesman_user_id]
GROUP BY u.title
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, definitely a more simple approach that might work. But there remain an issus: I have hundreds of successful quotes, so I needed to make the query above manually for every single quote? How can I get that into one single query?

Comment: That's a way more complicated question.  You haven't given enough parameters to even begin answering it.  For instance: Are you looking to get all tradesmen at a particular time?  Since a particular employer made their last request?  From their most recent approval?  A subset of employers or tradesmen or both? -- I recommend asking a new question on StackOverflow once you can define exactly what it is you are looking for.

Comment: I see. Need to restructure my question. Thanks anyway.